# Compiler exception from/within a method

Tags: c#

**Background:**
We have a legacy library in which a specific method returns an unmanaged resource (file handle). The consumers of this library work with that file handle and dispose once they are done with it. The library currently externalize the dispose since only consumer can dictate when it is safe to dispose.

It so happen in some scenario where the consumer leave the file handler as is even after the purpose and this causes memory leak. To avoid this, we are in process of standardizing consumer call where it deterministically dispose the file handle.

**Question:** Is it possible to throw a compiler exception from/within a method if it is not adhere to any required standard. Eg: We wanted to ensure that the consumer is disposing the file handle within their implementation and if not throw a compiler generated exception.
We are open to any approach including custom attributes, custom fxcope rule etc.

Comment: sounds like a job for a custom fxcop rule, or maybe roslyn (ctp) - however, handling *all* cases is very complex (think: halting-problem) - the best you'll probably be able to do is the "obvious" uses

Comment: A compiler cannot determine what happens at runtime... This woould be a runtime exception

Comment: Can you create a new API that wraps the legacy library? Your new API consumers would access (instead of accessing the legacy library directly). At that point, you can probably better manage usage, say by implementing `IDisposable`, perhaps keeping a timer around to automatically dispose the resource after a reasonable time, implementing destructors (taking to account all their caveats), or however you wish.

Comment: @bash.d the compiler (or more correctly: build-time code-analysis tools, not the compiler itself) can analyse the callers, though

Comment: Calling Dispose() is optional, there is no way you can force a client program to call it.  This isn't a problem, you always have the GC to back you up.  As long as you don't return an IntPtr.  Use a SafeFileHandle or FileStream.

Comment: The wrap is something which we already thought about. But the concern is that, we can't dictate the life of the handle.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thank you for the advise. Meantime, the  legacy library is been around for a while and is been used by multiple application with our product suite. So changing the method to return a SafeFileHandle or any modification on the existing code is less likely to happen. As this is more of a rule which we are trying to enforce, we would like to have it with less impact. This is why we were in direction of having attribute/ custom fxcop rule based approach. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Custom rule is something which make more sense for us and would definitely appreciate a head start on that side.

Comment: So you are returning an IntPtr then?  That's of course very troublesome, nothing is stopping you from improving your code by adding another method that does it right.

Comment: @HansPassant, We thought about it of having a wrap method (which uses the actual legacy) which return the handle and do the house keeping. But the concern is, we can't predict the life of handle which is been supplied to consumer unless they say so. Meantime, we are thinking of having some kind of a callback which eventually will execute once the consumer done with the actual handle. And this call back will remove and dispose handle from a collection which is maintained within wrap object. But nothing materialized so far.

Comment: You refuse to be specific, very hard to help you.  Of course a "callback" doesn't work either, even less likely they'll call it.  If this needs to be tracked in a collection then use a WeakReference to know that the object got garbage-collected.